# Android EditText, getting ALL the states

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-drawable, android-selector

I have a trivial XML drawable happy_borders.xml which is to be the background for some EditText.

```
        <EditText
            android:background="@drawable/happy_borders
```

Of course that doesn't work, because on **many/most devices it will *focus* the first one, and then you get nothing as the background**.

So you do something like this ... file happy_states.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- res/drawable/rounded_edittext_states.xml -->
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/happy_borders" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/happy_borders" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/happy_borders" />
</selector>
```

and then

```
        <EditText
            android:background="@drawable/happy_states
```

No problem but

(1) there are actually an enormous list of `android:state_ ...` - what's the deal there?  In the `selector` is there a way to imply "do this for every state"??

(2) alternately.  Inside an EditText.  Can you tell it to be "stateless" and never, ever, concern itself with states?  ie, use only the one background ever?

Note that in many cases it's better engineering, I think, to just put a separate view behind the EditText; but anyway I want to know how to achieve (1) or (2) above.

Comment: "use only the one background ever?" -- distinguishing between focused and unfocused states is important for UX where the touchscreen does not exist (e.g., TV) or is not being used for current interaction (e.g., keyboard).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define states that require a different drawable and then add a default state at the end:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- res/drawable/rounded_edittext_states.xml -->
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/happy_borders" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/sad_borders" />
</selector>
```

**EDIT:**
Sorry, didn't quite answer your questions:

1) If you don't define any non-default states, then default one is "do this for every state".

2) I believe no, probably the solution is to set background to `null` or specific `drawable`.

To be clear this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- res/drawable/rounded_edittext_states.xml -->
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/default_borders" />
</selector>
```

is all that is needed, to have "no states"; to have every state the same.